# Remove localization storyboards

Tags: objective-c, internationalization, storyboard

I've tried out localization and followed "[This](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/)" guide months ago. Then kept developing without keeping up with the other storyboards (i.e adding to the base and not supporting lets say the Spanish storyboard).
as a result when an iPhone with Spanish language interface is defined my application gets crashed cause it's looking for the Spanish storyboard,

I went back to the properties of the project removed the **use internationalization** as well as delete (using the -) the Spanish language

as a result my story board disappeared from the solution, and the application still gets crashed when language is defined to Spanish.

My Questions:

1. Is there a way to develop on one storyboard and it will automatically update the rest?
2. Is there a way to develop only on one storyboard and all languages will run with it?
3. How can I find & restore the storyboard in my solution

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use one storyboard to handle localization.

First, you should create a macro that will localize your strings:

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

Then, you can create a category on each of the UI elements you would like to localize. For example, for UILabel, you could create:

```
UILabel+Localization.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabel (Localization)

@end
```

And:

```
UILabel+Localization.m

#import "UILabel+Localization.h"

@implementation UILabel (Localization)

-(void)setLocalizeKey:(NSString*)key {
  self.text = NSLocalizedString(key, nil);
}

@end
```

After that, in the UIStoryboard you select the element you would like to localize and in the identity inspector add a User Defined Runtime Attribute that will set the localized key:

[image: localized key in user defined runtime attributes]